# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 installation create an extended partition besides the swap?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a 200-GB hard-disk (with 4-GB ram installed). When I let the installation do partitioning for me, it created the following partitions.

Ubuntu auto-partitioning on 200GB hard disk with 4GB ram:

[image]

The images shows the following partitions,

1. Filesystem - 196 GB Ext4 (`/dev/sda1`)
2. Extended Partition - 4.2 GB (`/dev/sda2`) (highlighted in the image)
3. Swap - 4.2 GB (`/dev/sda5`)

I canceled and restarted the installation to check how those partitions look like. At one step in the installation you can see the current partitions, and I didn't find the extended partition (highlighted in the image), which means it's not in use. Then why Ubuntu Installation created this partition?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The installer, which Ubuntu inherited from Debian, wants to make `sda1` to hold the root filesystem and `sda5` to hold the swap area, for reasons which were never articulated and are forever lost in the mist of time. It cannot create `sda5` directly, because the old-style Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table cannot have more than 4 entries; to make more than 4 partitions on a MBR-partitioned disk one has to designate one of those 4 entries as an "extended partition" and make the extra partition(s) inside it. Thus you get `sda1` for the root file system, an extended partition, and `sda5` inside the extended partition. Note that the extended partition is just a container for `sda5`, it does not have any disk space of its own.

You can always opt for manual partitioning and create the partitions the way you want them to be.

Comment: Hi, Thank You! Did you see the images I included?

Comment: Yes, there is an image. I did not see it when I first read the question, but now I see it. Strange.

Comment: But if we add 196GB + 4.2 GB = 200GB, so you are right that the partition above doesn't exist actually, its just a container.

Comment: Would you please edit my question and embed the (2nd) image, I just included the link, because I don't have enough privileges to embed it. It will be better for the future readers.

Comment: There are now _two_ images... And the question has a note that it was edited by muru.

Comment: If you wanted to have sda1 as your root file system and sda2 as your swap, the way that Ubuntu's installer would automatically do it would be if your hard drive were formatted with a GPT partition table instead of the old MBR partitioning that it seems to have.  As stated in the answer above, the old MBR partition table can only have 4 primary partitions, thus the need to create an extended partition for the swap to be placed inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

The swap partition is made as an extended partition to make it simpler to add extra partitions later. This way, there's space for future changes with minimal impact.

Else if you even add another partition by shrinking the sda1 and making a new primary, the swap may just change to sda3 instead of sda5. In which case some settings will have to be adjusted so it can still be used.